# How can I calculate the average speed?

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, calculator

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():

        print("Entry time: %s\nEntry distance: %s\nAverage Speed =(e1*e2)" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Enter entry time").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Enter entry distance").grid(row=1)


e1 = Entry(master)

e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

e2.grid(row=1, column=1)


Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)

Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

`mainloop( )`

I am trying to make a program that caluculates the average speed but so far i'm going wrong somewhere...

Comment: Please tell us exactly what problems you are encountering. Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 print("Entry time: %s\nEntry distance: %s\nAverage Speed =(e1*e2)" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))
```

1. `print("(e1*e2)")` is just printing some text, it's not doing any calculation.
2. It can't do some calculation because you aren't storing the results of `get()`. Depending on whether .get() is returning a stored number or prompting the user, this might not need storing, but it needs to be consistant - either e1 and e2 are numbers that you can do calculation on, or you need to .get() numbers out of them. You switch from one pattern to the other.
3. Average speed isn't time*distance, it's distance/time.
4. It's using old-style string interpolation

e.g. (untested)

```
    t=float(e1.get())
    d=float(e2.get())
    print("Entry time: {0}\nEntry distance: {1}\nAverage Speed = {2}".format(t, d, d/t))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to tessellatingHeckler in show_field function print "e1*e2" will print e1*e2.

- to overcome problem convert the string value in float ex
  e1value = (float)e1.get()
  e2value = (float)e2.get()
  Val = (str)e1value*e2value
  Print "%s" %(Val)